Trouble Viewing Change Details in Audit History Component
As a system admin user, I set up the opportunity split in Salesforce. After setting it up, I did the following:

I turned on field history tracking for Opportunity Team, Opportunity
Split, and Opportunity Product Split.
I added the "Audit History" component to the lightning page,
Created records for opportunity team  and split
Audit history not showing the details of changes made.

Please find the screenshots below

Do I need to add additional permissions to display the Audit History details?
Document referred :-  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.teamselling_set_up_audit_history.htm&type=5

Hi @Annappa I am also facing the same issue. Please post if you find any solution for this.

It is known issue from salesforce side:-  https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000zIfKjAAK/the-opportunity-audit-history-component-does-not-display-any-data-for-the-opportunity-splits-and-opportunity-teams
